# Why is there no 401a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think there should be a 401a tag, I don't understand how that doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably know, it takes a certain level of reputation to create new tags: https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

And it would appear that no government employees with a 401(a) account have had any questions about them until now.

I added the tag for you

Comment: Even Wikipedia doesn't care about the 401(a) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/401%28a%29